# Disabling all CALayer default actions in one action

Tags: ios, action, calayer

Does anyone know if there's a short-hand or convient way of disabling all of the default CALayer actions in one short statement? A way without having to create a dictionary full of [NSNull null]'s for every action? I've scoured just about everything I have at my disposal but whilst there are several examples of how to disable specific actions using an NSDictionary - there seems to be nothing about disabling everything in one hit.

Comment: Do you mean CALayer default animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily disable layer actions.

```
if ([StateManager isGameInProgress]){
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue: (id) kCFBooleanTrue forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions];
    [self drawLoop];
    [self logicLoop];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Transactions.html

Comment: Thanks for this, Mark. I'll experiment with it.